# Including background-image to child div

Tags: html, background-image, parent-child

I am doing one project where I have parent div and a child div, I need to include background-image to child div.

for example,

```
<div class="parent_div">
   <div class="child_div">
    ..... content .....
   </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if anyone can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jayata.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be honest, this is a simple thing and can be found easily by performing a search on Google or Stack Overflow.  Perhaps reading the [help] and taking the [tour] would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
<style>
.child_div{background:url('your_image_path/image_name.png')}
</style>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably can find any question related to yours... Anyway, here is the answer:

If you don't have classes to refer to those divs, use the following generic snippet.

```
div div{
background: url("path_to_your_image") //and some other parameters about your background
}
```

**It's highly recommended to use classes to identify** `div`, because the snippet above is generic for all divs that contain another `div` (mostly). Otherwise, I used a shorthand of `background` property, but you can use the long version (shorthand recommended), which should looks like:

```
div div{
background-image: url("path_to_your_image");
background-size: cover //or whatever you need;
background-position: center center //or whatever you need;
background-repeat: no-repeat //or repeat if needed
}
```

Using classes, it should looks like:

```
.parent_class .child_class{
//same snippet than above
}
```